# JQuery jCarrousel Lite

Tags: jquery

Estou usando o `plugin` do `JCarousel Lite` e ele funcionou bem em uma determinada página.
Agora estou aplicando em outra página do msm projeto só que ao invés de funcionar, ele coloca `widht: 0px height: 0px;` em todas os elementos e na propria div alvo.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Comment: Deverá ser conflito de css's. Tente dar uma olhadela nas classes. Poste mais detalhes das suas classes css que está a usar

Comment: Estou usando .less e até então funcionava direitinho.

Comment: Mas se o css está a alterar pode ser conflito de nome de classes css

Comment: Estou sendo BEM específico no meu css. Não pode ser conflito além do que o Chrome Developer Tools não acusa conflito.

Comment: Até podes ter o teu css bem específico, mas não sabes as classes css que o JCarousel Lite está a criar. É possível que exista duas classes com o mesmo nome ou assim. Mas se não acusa conflito não estou a ver do que possa ser

Answer (score 1):

Cara, tente tirar o css e deixa o JCarousel Lite sozinho pra ver se funciona. Se funcionar, de alguma forma seu CSS está afetando.

Comment: partilho da mesma opinião

Comment: Preciso basicamente de uma div que receba o jcarousel, uma ul com li's pra ele saber o tamanho do Widht que ele vai colocar no código. No pé em que estou não da pra tirar qualquer css. Mas como disse, eu uso .less e não é possivel que esteja recebendo qualquer herança.